# How do I switch between page edit mode and template edit mode in the Visual Studio 2012 design view?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, blend

When using the design view in VS 2012, if you right click on an element and select one of the templates from **Edit Template** or **Edit Additional Templates**, it takes you to a new view within the designer.

This may be a silly question, but how do I navigate back out to the main view?

In Blend, I just use the little up arrow next to the template name but that doesn't seem to exist in VS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to return is to double-click on the artboard, just outside the template area.

Another, that is more in line with what you are used to from Blend can be found in the Document Outline panel. There is that little arrow.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the Document Outline panel, that's exactly what I was looking for. And the double-click part is also something I didn't know about. Thanks a lot!